# On the existence of a power series given a power series and an affine map vanishing on a hyperplane.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove the following result, which is an exercise problem from the book "Lie groups, Lie algebras and Representations" by B. C. Hall.

> **Theorem:** Let $V$ be a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$, not necessarily passing through origin, and let $L: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a affine map whose zero-set is precisely $V$. Suppose $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a globally convergent power series in $n$ variables which vanishes on $V$. Then,
>
> 1. There is a globally convergent power series $h: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $g = Lh$.
> 2. If $g$ vanishes on some hyperplane $V'$ distinct from $V$, then $h$ vanishes on $V'$.

Clearly, point (2) easily follows from (1), since distinct hyperplane can intersect in an affine subspace of strictly lower dimension. Then, at every point not in the intersection $V \cap V'$ but in $V'$, $g$ must vanish but $L$ does not vanish, and hence $h$ must vanish. On the other hand, if $v \in V \cap V'$, every open set containing $v$ must intersect $V'$ and hence by the continuity of $h$ (being a convergent power series), we must have $h \left( v \right) = 0$.

However, I am unable to prove the existence of such a power series $h$. The hint given y the author is to choose a coordinate system with origin in $V$ (from which I infer that we have to shift the origin to a point in $V$ so that $L$ becomes a linear map) such that $L \left( x \right) = x_1$, if $x = \left( x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \right)$ in the coordinate system.

First, I am unable to see as to how exactly are we supposed to shift the origin? Will the affine constant (i.e., if we write $Lx = Tx + c$, then $c$ will be the affine constant) help in it? Secondly, even if we do it, how does it prove the existence of $h$?

Any help in this regard will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you solve the even more special case that the hyperplane is given by $x_n=0$?

Comment: For your first question, note that after choosing some arbitrary $v_0\in V$, the map $x\mapsto L(x+v_0)$ is linear $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.  That is what the author meant by shifting the origin to a point in $V$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, no I have no idea to construct the power series $h$. That is the main problem. I think the translation (shift of origin) will not be that much of a problem once we understand how to construct $h$ for a hyperplane passing through the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split the full result into three steps, some of which you may already have learned about:

- If $g$ is a globally convergent power series and $c\in \Bbb R^n$, then so is $x\mapsto g(x+c)$
- If $g$ is a globally convergent power series and $A\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ a matrix, then so is $x\mapsto g(Ax)$
- If $g$ is a globally convergent power series such that $g(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0)=0$ for all $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\in \Bbb R^{n-1}$, then $g=x_nh$ for a globally convergent power series $h$

Comment: Thanks for the outline! It is much easier to see this way. Only one trivial doubt: Say we write $g = \sum\limits_{i_1\cdots i_n = 0}^{\infty} a_{i_1\cdots i_n} x_1^{i_1}\cdots x_n^{i_n}$, then from the condition $g(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1},0) = 0$, we get that $\sum\limits_{i_1\cdots i_{n-1}=0}^{\infty}a_{i_1\cdots i_{n-1}0}x^{i_1}\cdots x_{n-1}^{i_{n-1}} = 0$. Then, from here can we directly say that all coefficients are zero since the right hand side is a globally convergent power series on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ which is identically zero? Or is there some more analysis that is required?